# Is there any IDE for fast drag and drop php development?

Tags: php, ide

I am using  Eclipse IDE with few plug-ins for PHP dev. I am using PHPEclipse plug-in and I know there are lotsa other plugins like EasyEclipse.But is there an IDE like Visual Studio with cool drag and drop stuff for PHP?

Comment: He is looking for a RAD tool like the other half of the people who have the title "programmer". What's so wrong about it? After all, RAD has real value and people do make big money selling RAD tools.

Comment: You also can use: http://www.linb.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use APTANA.

You can get it here http://www.aptana.com/

It's my web IDE of choice.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Windows you might want to take a look at the (somewhat unfortunately named) "[Delphi for PHP](http://www.codegear.com/products/delphi/php)" from CodeGear / Emabarcadero which I hear mostly good things about - at least for new development that is as it's rather closely tied to a specific framework ([VCL for PHP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vcl4php/), which is Open Source), which makes it somewhat less of an interesting option for maintaining existing projects.

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer the Open source because it gives us freedom to change the code. so i will strongly recommend someone looking to use drag and drop ide the [VisualJS](http://www.linb.net/VisualJS/) i think this is the best available with very fast development and gives freedom use to use any server side language.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to drag and drop? If I'm not mistaken most dragging and dropping in Visual Studio has to do with the GUI and that is completely different from the way PHP works (rendering a web page). You might try a WYSIWYG webpage design tool like Dreamweaver (commercial) or maybe something like Nvu (free, open source). But that wont help you developing the actual php 'behind' the page.

Comment: By drag and drop I meant almost everything.If you see VS 2008 you can literally use drag and drop to even create the database layer and lots of code behind stuff.I was thinking if there is anything that powerful as VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a **GUI drag-and-drop web widgets framework** - TIBCO GI, Rialto, etc.
They're not PHP per se, but [this wikipedia list of widget toolkits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits#Cross-platform) will help a lot

Answer (score 0):

RapidPHP is one of the great PHP IDE as per my experience. Its so simple yet powerful.